# jquery ajax load() does not load internal css for webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

The css part is totally not reflected in the output (for webkit only, others ok), it is as if no css was defined, javascript works tho...

Ajax call

```
    $("#output_area").load("abc.html");
```

abc.html sourcecode: (Angle brackets are omitted)

```
!DOCTYPE HTML
html
    head
        style type="text/css"

            css..
            css..
            css..

            NOT LOADED/REFLECTED IN THE OUTPUT

        /style
    /head
    body

        HTML...
        HTML...
        HTML...

        script type="text/javascript"

            JAVASCRIPT IS LOADED AND IT WORKS

        /script
    /body
/html
```

Comment: a quick smart guess: try putting that style block inside the body, i am assuming jquery's load function ignores the head block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loading css rules dynamically in Webkit (Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351633/loading-css-rules-dynamically-in-webkit-safari-chrome)