# Javascript set CSS :after styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can you set the :after styles of css with Javascript?

So lets say:

```
$("#foo li:after").css("left","100px");
```

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Comment: Added the jQuery tag as you seem to be using it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var addRule = (function(style){
    var sheet = document.head.appendChild(style).sheet;
    return function(selector, css){
        var propText = Object.keys(css).map(function(p){
            return p+":"+css[p]
        }).join(";");
        sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + propText + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
    }
})(document.createElement("style"));

addRule("p:before", {
    display: "block",
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    background: "red",
    "border-radius": "50%",
    content: "''"
});
```

A minimal implementation. You most likely would want to keep track of the rules you add so you can remove them. `sheet.insertRule` returns the index of the new rule which you can use to get a reference to it for editing or removal.

Edit: added basic functionality to convert an object into a css property string for convenience.

Comment: Seems like the `content:` property is not getting included.