# how to create inline style with :before and :after

Tags: css, inline

I generated a bubble chat thingy from http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/

In my page I put a number inside of it

```
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: -4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 4px 3px 0;
  border-color: transparent #FFF;
   display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: -5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 4px 3px 0;
  border-color: transparent #000;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I want the `background-color` of the bubble to change according to the number inside of it via `rgb`

so if my div is

```
<div class="bubble" style="background-color: rgb(100,255,255);"> 100 </div>
```

I want the color to be `rgb(100,255,255)`

The thing is this doesn't affect the triangle.

How do I write the inline css so it will include the :before and :after?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can't. With inline styles you are targeting the element directly. You can't use other selectors there.

What you can do however is define different classes in your stylesheet that define different colours and then add the class to the element.

Comment: can i do it with javascript?

Comment: Apparently yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330355/javascript-set-css-after-styles

Comment: @NickGinanto sure you can - it just won't work :D your fighting here with browser internals, you cannot reinvent the weel with a language laying on top of that...

Comment: Oddly, in spite of being marked as 'The Answer', this answer is quite incorrect. See Nathan Arthur's answer above.

Answer (score 129):

You can, using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) (more precisely called CSS custom properties).

- Set your variable in your style attribute: 
  `style="--my-color-var: orange;"`
- Use the variable in your stylesheet: 
  `background-color: var(--my-color-var);`

[Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/css-variables)

## Minimal example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:after {
  background-color: var(--my-color-var);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="--my-color-var: orange;"></div>
```

## Your example:

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: var(--bubble-color);
}

.bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: -4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 4px 3px 0;
  border-color: transparent var(--bubble-color);
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

.bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: -5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 4px 3px 0;
  border-color: transparent #000;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='bubble' style="--bubble-color: rgb(100,255,255);"> 100 </div>
```

Comment: Not supported by Internet Explorer, unfortunately

Comment: Yup, if you need to support IE, you'll want to limit custom properties to use cases that won't cripple website functionality for IE users. In other words, use progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 57):

The key is to use `background-color: inherit;` on the pseudo element.
 See: http://jsfiddle.net/EdUmc/

Comment: good answer. inheritance can be very very handy with :after when you want things like arrows made out of borders with parent-dependent colors...

Answer (score 18):

If you really need it inline, for example because you are loading some user-defined colors dynamically, you can always add a `<style>` element right before your content.

```
<style>#project-slide-1:before { color: #ff0000; }</style>
<div id="project-slide-1" class="project-slide"> ... </div>
```

---

Example use case with PHP and some (wordpress inspired) dummy functions:

```
<style>#project-slide-<?php the_ID() ?>:before { color: <?php the_field('color') ?>; }</style>
<div id="project-slide-<?php the_ID() ?>" class="project-slide"> ... </div>
```

Since HTML 5.2 it is valid to place style elements inside the body, although it is still recommend to place style elements in the head.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-style-element

Comment: great solution! It was perfect for my situation (aplying conditionals in liquid that affect styles).

Comment: emphasis on "if you really need it"! :)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved a similar problem by *border-color: inherit*

, see:

```
<li style="border-color: <?php echo $hex ?>;">...</li>

li {
    border-width: 0;
}

li:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two methods of adding color to an external SVG:
https://codepen.io/nathanhiemstra/pen/LYaMzOG?editors=1100

```css
.icon-mask {
    -webkit-mask-image: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/322934/path-distance.svg);
    mask-image: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/322934/path-distance.svg);
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: center center;
    mask-size: contain;
}

.icon-bg-image {
    background-image: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/322934/path-distance.svg);
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
}

.icon-red {
  background-color: #AD122A;
}
.icon-pink {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}

/* Get filter value from hex here: https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp */
.icon-filter-red {
  filter: invert(12%) sepia(77%) saturate(3846%) hue-rotate(340deg) brightness(103%) contrast(99%);
}

.icon-filter-pink {
  filter: invert(28%) sepia(100%) saturate(5081%) hue-rotate(296deg) brightness(114%) contrast(133%);
```

```html
<h4>Original</h4>
<i class="icon-bg-image"></i>

<h4>Image Mask on color background</h4>
<i class="icon-mask icon-red"></i>
<i class="icon-mask icon-pink"></i>

<h4>Filter on background image</h4>
<i class="icon-bg-image icon-filter-red"></i>
<i class="icon-bg-image icon-filter-pink"></i>
```