# Changing :before styling with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, colors, pseudo-element

I am wanting to change the color of the stars on this page using js *edit:link is now dead*

It is the :before on the class "star-rating" that is controlling the color but I have not been able to successfully change it, possibly because it has an important on it.

I read this but it didn't help [Javascript set CSS :after styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330355/javascript-set-css-after-styles)

Thanks

Alex

Comment: why you need js? it can be done only with css

Comment: I only want it to happen on certain pages, and I didn't make the theme so would rather stay out of the css files

Comment: so you can create your own stylesheet or put it on the head of the pages you want are you searching a solution for pure js or jquery too?

Comment: the pages are dynamically created by a plugin in Wordpress, js is the only way I can achieve what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the nicest way to do it, but

```
s = document.createElement('style') ; 
s.innerHTML = '.star-rating span:before, .star-rating:before, .woocommerce-page .star-rating:before { color:pink !important}' ; 
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

i.e. add a style tag to the head which overrides the style for those stars.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to remove and add new DOM for that stars or you can remove that !important from css and then change by using JS.

Otherwise use jquery and then :

```
starDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("star-rating")[0];
$(starDiv).css('color', 'red', 'important');
```

Comment: You can do that by using jquery but you are not using jquery