# Getting pseudo-element style values

Tags: javascript, css, dom, pseudo-element

Related to this question [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript), is there any way using javascript that I can access a pseudo-element's style attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the browser.  I don't believe IE supports this in any way, but for FireFox and Webkit browsers, you can use the following:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element, pseudo-selector);
```

For example:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':before');
```

See: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)