# Get the background styles of a pseudo element

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, pseudo-element

**Internet Explorer 8** doesn't allow to print background images.
Unfortunately I was asked to make this work.

There are "important" images in some pseudo elements which have to be printable.
I thought it might be possible to turn those background images into `<img/>` elements 
however it seems that it's not possible to **read styles of pseudo elements** in Internet Explorer 8 as it does not support `getComputedStyle`.

Any good ideas?

Related:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle
http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle/embed
[SO "Getting pseudo-element style values"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644399/getting-pseudo-element-style-values)

Comment: Not sure if this is a viable alternative - but have you considered using PhantomJS or something similar to take a virtual screenshot of the whole page and save it as an image then either redirect to the image or embed it in a PDF? It would guarantee that everything that should be visible would be printed at the cost of a slight change in flow

Comment: @Basic I think this is one of the best solutions for cross browser printing. However we aren't allowed to install wkhtmltopdf or phantomjs.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't mean install it on the client machine - I meant install it on the servers, generate the image there and serve it like any other image. Of course, if you're not able to install it on the servers, that's a bit of a show-stopper.

Comment: "`Internet Explorer 8 doesn't allow to print background images`". As far as I can remember, IE8 does allow to print background images. Only you need to tick a checkbox ("Print background colors and images") in Page Settings before printing.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var img = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('.element'), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('background');
```

**Edit**: I have a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXQ5R/) that doesn't use the `querySelector`:

```
var img = window.getComputedStyle(
    $(".element")[0], ':before'
).getPropertyValue('background');
```

Basically, you just want to get a element as first parameter in the `getComputedStyle`;

But that still doesn't fix the IE 8 requirement, as `getComputedStyle` isn't supported there, either... However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733365/cross-browser-ie8-getcomputedstyle-with-javascript) might provide the answer there.

Comment: This is exactly what I need.. However it doesn't work for Internet Explorer 8: http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle/embed

Comment: Derp, missed the IE8 requirement in the question. Lemme see what I can come up with.

Comment: @jantimon: Edited. Not a complete answer, but it has a suggestion that might work.

Comment: @Cerbrus : `document.getElementsByClassName` too would not work in IE8, Since the OP is using jQuery, `$(".element")` should work

Comment: @ClydeLobo: By now you can probably tell I usually don't bother with IE 8 and lower... Edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Cerbrus : Lucky you ;)