# How to change the color of Track for RANGE Input using Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here`s the HTML Input Range

```
<input id="golden_range" type="range">
```

I can change the Background Color of the Range Track to "#DDD" using this CSS

```
#golden_range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #DDD;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#golden_range::-moz-range-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #DDD;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

but i'm not able to change the background color using Jquery/Javascript. Please help me with this. Here's the code i'm trying to.

```
$('#golden_range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track').css('background', '#000');
$('#golden_range::-moz-range-track').css('background', '#000');
```

Comment: Better to use a class anyway …

Comment: Is there any specific event when you want to change the color? Put it inside `$(document).ready` function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)

Comment: i want to dynamically change the background color of the range input depending on the value of this range input. 
That`s why I cannot use CSS classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this now (2020) by making use of CSS variables.

#### CSS

```css
#golden_range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: var(--track-background, #ddd);
}

#golden_range::-moz-range-track {
  background: var(--track-background, #ddd);
}
```

#### Javascript

```js
document.querySelector('#golden_range').style.setProperty('--track-background', '#f00');
```

(should change the track background to red)

I'm doing this in [Player Chrome](https://github.com/muxinc/player-chrome) to style the media player progress bar, using a background gradient on the track to show progress.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code in your question, I see a mistake in your syntax. In css the background color property is written as "background-color: color_hex_value". This is how your css code should look like:

```
#golden_range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
  #golden_range::-moz-range-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

And this is the code for jquery:

```
$("#golden_range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track").css("background-color", "#000");
```

In case you are still having doubts, give a look at these two sources for [css background-color properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) and [Jquery css() method](http://jstricks.com/jquery-css-methods-selectors/).

Comment: yeah, i initially tried this but its also not working.

Comment: So as already suggested, or try to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript/12207551#answer-8051488

Answer (score 0):

Bad news. I have not found a proper way to do... but I found a dirty way; 
Insert a style tag in the body of the page. Of course, the content of this tag is generated with javascript:

```
var estilo = $("<style>").attr("id", "some_id");
//for Chrome, e.g.
 var mod= "::-webkit-slider-runnable-track";

var txt= "#id_range" + mod + " {\n";
txt+= "    background-color: rgb(100,100,100)\n";
txt+= "}\n";

estilo.text(txt);

$("#some_id").remove();
$("div#other_id").append(estilo);
```

it's ugly, slow and bad, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your files

**CSS:**

```
#golden_range.change::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #000;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#golden_range.change::-moz-range-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #000;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('input', '#golden_range', function() {
       var rangeValue = $(this).val(); 
       var changeRange = 20;
        if(currrentRange > changeRange){
            $("#golden_range").addClass("change");
        }
        });
```

***Note:*** Please check **changeRange** value and change as you want.