# Divide HTML range input track to parts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML range input component and I would like to divide the track to three different parts. I have a range of 0 to 75 in the component. I would like to style 0 to 25 as green, 26 to 50 as yellow and 51 to 75 as red irrespective of the input value, ie., the colors are constant. Is it possible to it? Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vamshikrishna144/p96chgz8/)

```js
var p = document.getElementById("price"),
    res = document.getElementById("result");

p.addEventListener("input", function() {
    res.innerHTML =  p.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 1em">
    <h2>Price</h2>
    0<input id="price" type="range" min="0" max="75" value="" />75
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://codepen.io/gabrieltomescu/pen/GsbIi
Or is this to complicated for your task?

Comment: @Nebulosar I have already seen this example, and it is not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't want the colors to overlap

Comment: Releated? -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373277/how-to-change-the-color-of-track-for-range-input-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: @Paulie_D Not really, the colors on the track should constants.

Comment: Yeah but you can do that with a gradient.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have updated my question by adding a picture for better understanding

Comment: gradient is the way to go i think, some tinkerering http://jsfiddle.net/Nebulosar/JnrvG/1003/ might get you there. If you always have these three positions it is just 33%, 33%, 33%

Comment: +1 to @Nebulosar commented solution - gradient is absolutely the way to go.  Simple, pure CSS, no markup revs needed.

Comment: @Nebulosar missing `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: True, missing a lot more too ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a `linear-gradient` background

```css
body {
text-align:center;
}  

#range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%, red 51%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#range::-moz-range-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%, red 51%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range">
```

Comment: In FF55 the gradient is quite broad, with the draggable part only going from a yellow to half way red :)

Comment: Seems to have been a `margin` issue...fixed.

Comment: Still not working for me, sorry. And yes, the principle is important, but giving a broken solution isn't really StackOverflow-style :)

Comment: linear-gradient(to right, green 33%, yellow 34%, yellow 66%, red 67%) would fix the issue, I'm waiting for my edit to get peer reviewed

Comment: Fiddled a bit with your snippet, changing width:300px to 100% seems to fix it :)

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D

Comment: Thank you @Martijn

Comment: 1/3 each does not match your initial requirements.