# querySelectorAll - Can I put a selector with ":after"?

Tags: javascript, css, selectors-api

Can I do this in JavaScript?

```js
var Dim_Back = document.querySelectorAll(".s1:after");
for (var i = 0; i < Dim_Back.length; i++) {
                Dim_Back[i].style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgSrc + ")";
            }
```

```css
.view .s1:after {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                content: '';
                display: block;
                opacity: 0;
                transition-delay: 0.3s;
            }

            .view:hover .s1:after {
                opacity: 1;
                transition-delay: 0.7s;
            }
```

I also put a part from my CSS code.

I want to know if I can put the ":after" inside a querySelectorAll. Will it maintain s1 properties?

Comment: Did you mean `::after`?

Comment: @Bergi  Isn't the same thing?

Comment: Maybe, though technically only with two colons it's a pseudo-element.

Comment: possbile duplicate of [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4481485/1048572)

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you are using (relatively) modern browser, then - yes, you can!

```
const myElement = document.querySelector('your-element-selector')
const myPseudoElement = window.getComputedStyle(myElement, ':after')
```

You can then use `getPropertyValue` to retrieve css values. for instance:

```
const originalBackgroundValue = myPseudoElement.getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/how-tos-for-coders/https-medium-com-kaushalshah1307-get-pseudo-elements-using-javascript-b64c88a96c46)

If you also wish to update values, please use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element)

Answer (score 3):

You can't manipulate `:after` in Javascript, but you can play with class toggles like [Access the css ":after" selector with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery) .

**EDIT:**
Could you maybe explain more the context?
Otherwise, this is not about jQuery, but about the method:

JS

```
var Dim_Back = document.querySelectorAll(".s1"),
    Dim_class = 'activeBg',
    el;

for (var i = 0; i < Dim_Back.length; i++) {
    el = Dim_Back[i];
    if (el.classList){
       el.classList.add(Dim_class);
    } else {
       el.className += ' ' + Dim_class;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.view .s1:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.view .s1.activeBg:after {
    background: URL('/your_image.png');
}
.view:hover .s1:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

I don't know if it's really accurate, but it was to develop my point. Hope it might help.

Good Luck'

Comment: or you can use `document.getElementById('foo2').nextSibling;`

Comment: @RedBreast  I don't know how to work with jQuery. If there is a way to do it in javaScript, please tell me.     P.S. please see the modification I made in my code. Maybe you will get an idea of what I am trying to do :)

Comment: @Deni2994 As I'm fairly new here, I don't know if the post edit send you a notification. Have a look on it.

Comment: @ozil I actually did not know this method. Does it work on pseudo-elements?

Comment: @RedBreast  It doesn't work. I'll post a question with all my code and a demo and then I will give you the link to see what exactly I have to do.

Comment: I have put my whole code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560228/javascript-see-the-back-on-folding-simulation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want also to change style value of elements with selector ":after" you can do something like this:

```js
    const a = document.querySelector('.a');
    a.classList.add("b");
```

```css
    .a:after
    {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .b:after
    {
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="a"></div>
```