# How to get pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, html, pseudo-element

I need to get `:after` and assign it to variable. It is possible?

`querySelectorAll` doesn't work.

```
alert(some_div_with_pseudo.querySelectorAll('::after')[0]) // undefined
```

Comment: You _cannot_, as the name 'pseudo' implies. These are not part of the actual DOM, they are, to javascript, style rules applied to an actual element.

Comment: JavaScript *absolutely* can read/write CSS pseudo `content`; see my answer below for a *write-mode* example.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other question. You will note that the other question involves jQuery, and the selected answer doesn’t answer this one.

Answer (score 66):

The short answer is that you can’t. It’s not there yet.

JavaScript has access to the DOM, which is built when the page is loaded from HTML, and modified further when JavaScript manipulates it.

A **pseudo element** is generated by CSS, rather than HTML or JavaScript. It is there purely to give CSS something to hang on to, but it all happens without JavaScript having any idea.

This is how it should be. In the overall scheme of things, the pages starts off as HTML. JavaScript can be used to modify its behaviour and to manipulate the content on one hand, and CSS can be used to control the presentation of the result:

```
HTML [→ JavaScript] → CSS → Result
```

You’ll see that CSS, complete with pseudo elements, comes at the end, so JavaScript doesn’t get a look in.

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Usage_notes
- https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar

**Edit**

It seems that in modern JavaScript there is a workaround using `window.getComputedStyle(element,pseudoElement)`:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(' … ');
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(element,':after')
var content = styles['content'];
```

Comment: The problem with getComputedStyle is that if you put the wrong literal, you will get the same result as if you didn't put the 2nd variable at all, e.g. getComputedStyle(element,':afterrrr')==getComputedStyle(element) so the function behaves wierdly.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get updated styles when the pseudo element is `:hover`ed or `:active`. It seems `getComputedStyle` only returns the original style of the pseudo element. `getComputedStyle` does, however, return the updated the style of ***regular*** elements when they're `:hover`ed or `:active`

Comment: I don't know that the edit is the proper solution to the question but it certainly is a correct answer the problem I had!

Comment: @NathanB well that's about the same error/bug as if you'd use the wrong selector in the `querySelector`, so your comment to me is pretty much moot. All of these are string magic values and they can always be mistyped until discovered...

Answer (score 41):

You can do this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('somedivId'), ':after'
);
```

Sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/cfwmqbvn/

Comment: It return style. I need element

Comment: ":after" is a pseudo element, not an element. You can not return a dom node, it isn't one - all you can do it get the styles :)

Comment: @MrBizle Its a shadow dom element.

Comment: @MrBizle how can I check if the pseudo element exist?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get updated styles when the pseudo element is `:hover`ed or `:active`. It seems `getComputedStyle` only returns the original style of the pseudo element. `getComputedStyle` does, however, return the updated the style of regular elements when they're `:hover`ed or `:active`

Answer (score 7):

Changing or setting the style of CSS pseudo-element is a tricky one, actually, you can not do this directly or maybe I do not know the way yet, but I will share a **technique** with you to do this.

-Use **CSS variable** to design your CSS pseudo-element and **change the value of the variable using javascript** and this will change the style of your CSS pseudo-element.

**CSS:**

```
 #box::after{
 content: 'this is after';
 background-color: var(--boxAfterBackColor,red);
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 right: 0px;
 font-size: var(--boxAfterFontSize,20px);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let box = document.getElementById('box');
box.style.setProperty('--boxAfterBackColor','green');
box.style.setProperty('--boxAfterFontSize','50px');
```

*This works for me, hope it will help you too. Best of Luck!*

Comment: This is brilliant!  

I had an unusual situation where this method was the best alternative.  I wanted to style a React forwardRef component.  When I used the styled-components library and jest-styled-components, the jest snapshots still had the random className in the forwardRef node.  This method allows me to ditch the styled-component so the snapshots work as expected.

Comment: By far the best answer. Nice job!

Comment: Doesn't work. My browser (Brave) tells me it's an invalid property :-/

Comment: tremendously clever.

Answer (score 5):

I use an arrow pointing in the direction that the content and sidebar will toggle to/from via a CSS pseudo-element. The code below is effectively a *write* mode however it is entirely possible to read CSS pseudo-element `content` as well.

Since there is a bit involved I'll also post the prerequisites (source: JAB Creations web platform JavaScript documentation, if anything missing look it up there) so those who wish to try it out can fairly quickly do so.

**CSS**

```
#menu a[href*='sidebar']::after {content: '\2192' !important;}
```

**JavaScript Use**

```
css_rule_set('#menu a[href*="sidebar"]::after','content','"\u2192"','important');
```

**JavaScript Prerequisites**

```
var sidebar = 20;


function id_(id)
{
 return (document.getElementById(id)) ? document.getElementById(id) : false;
}


function css_rule_set(selector,property,value,important)
{
 try
 {
  for (var i = 0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++)
  {
   var ss = document.styleSheets[i];
   var r = ss.cssRules ? ss.cssRules : ss.rules;

   for (var j = 0; j<r.length; j++)
   {
    if (r[j].selectorText && r[j].selectorText==selector)
    {
     if (typeof important=='undefined') {r[j].style.setProperty(property,value);}
     else {r[j].style.setProperty(property,value,'important');}
     break;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 catch(e) {if (e.name !== 'SecurityError') {console.log('Developer: '+e);}}
}


function sidebar_toggle()
{
 if (id_('menu_mobile')) {id_('menu_mobile').checked = false;}

 if (getComputedStyle(id_('side')).getPropertyValue('display') == 'none')
 {
  css_rule_set('#menu a[href*="sidebar"]::after','content','"\u2192"','important');

  if (is_mobile())
  {
   css_rule_set('main','display','none','important');
   css_rule_set('#side','width','100%','important');
   css_rule_set('#side','display','block','important');
  }
  else
  {
   css_rule_set('main','width',(100 - sidebar)+'%');
   css_rule_set('#side','display','block');
  }
 }
 else
 {
  css_rule_set('#menu a[href*="sidebar"]::after','content','"\u2190"','important');

  if (is_mobile())
  {
   css_rule_set('main','display','block','important');
   css_rule_set('main','width','100%','important');
   css_rule_set('#side','display','none','important');
  }
  else
  {
   css_rule_set('main','width','100%','important');
   css_rule_set('#side','display','none');
  }
 }
```

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. If I'm understanding this correctly, you're getting looping through the styleSheet objects, looking within those for selectors that match your target (in the case of the pseudo element `'#menu a[href*="sidebar"]::after'` ) and then updating the individual declaration within that with the new value you provide? It isn't the usecase in this question, but this would only work if there is already an existing style declaration targeting the pseudo element right?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way in JavaScript to access value of pseudo elements without any library. To get the value, you need to use the 'getComputedStyle' function. The second parameter is optional.

```
let elem = window.getComputedStyle(parent, ':before');
alert(elem.getPropertyValue('background'))
```

This will do alert the value of pseudo element.

Comment: But is there a way to list all the pseduo elements?

Answer (score 0):

let elem = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#item'), ':after');
console.log(elem.getPropertyValue('content'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).