# How do I add :after in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

html:

This is what I have

```
<div class="one"> Apple  </div>
```

I want to add the word "juice"  using javascript `.style`. Is there a equivalent to `:: after` where I can set the content in javascript using `.style.after = "juice"`?

```
<div class="one"> Apple Juice </div>
```

js:

```
document.querySelector('.one').style.display ="inline";
document.querySelector('.one').style.marginLeft ="2px";
document.querySelector('.one').style. =
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript/14106897

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a rather odd way of achieving what you want:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerText = '.one::after { ... }';
document.body.appendChild(style)
```

So essentially just creating an entirely new `<style></style>` element and adding your pseudo selector styles there, and appending it to the body.