# angular testbed, query by css, find the pseudo element

Tags: css, angular, unit-testing, pseudo-element

I am writhing Angular 2+ unit test with TestBed.
Scenario, I want to verify my component, that the color of a pseudo element.

component.ts

```css
label::before {
        right: 0;
        background-color: red;
      }
```

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <div><label>a label</label></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
})
export class TestComponent {
  
}
```

so when I write unit test, I want to verify the pseudo element background color

```
  beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should set background color', () => {
  const ele = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('label::before')).nativeElement; // error here
  // not sure how to use by.css to locate on the pseudo element
  expect(ele.backgroundColor).toBe('....');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing your test in a different manner.

Fixture is of type `ComponentFixture<T>` where `T` is the component you are trying to access. The `debugElement` property has two properties that you are *normally* interested In when writing a test `componentInstance` and `nativeElement`

`ComponentInstance` is your component `ts` file. It's your class declaration in a sense.

`NativeElement` as the name suggests is the mark-up or your `template`

I don't think it's possible to do it the way you suggested.

However you could try

```
  const color =  window.getComputedStyle(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('label'), ':after').getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

This will give you a rgb result so for red it would be `rgb(255,0,0)`

I got this from: [How to get pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element)

Try this and see if it works. It's not great that we had to access the window element inside of our test but it might solve your issue. Possibly create a better test without having to access the window api i would suggest.