# js - querySelector pick and edit styles in pseudoclass ::before

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get with querySelector method an element with pseudoclass ::before, How can i do this in vanilla Js? This is my attempt:

```js
const menuDropdown = document.querySelectorAll('[class$="menu-dropdown"');
const about = document.querySelector('#about');

about.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {

    for(let el of menuDropdown) {
        console.log(el);
        el.style.opacity = '1';
        el.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

})
```

```css
.menu-dropdown:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <ul class="menu-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Aktualności</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nasz team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element)

Comment: Simple, add a class instead, why are you applying inline styles?

Comment: Instead what ? I don't know where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the code to show the opacity of the pseudo element of the element the mouse is over.

```js
const menuDropdown = document.querySelector('.menu-dropdown');
const about = document.querySelector('#about');

about.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
  menuDropdown.classList.add('make-visible');
});
about.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
 menuDropdown.classList.remove('make-visible');
});
```

```css
.menu-dropdown:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.make-visible:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <ul class="menu-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Aktualności</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nasz team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I can show opacity value, but how to change it ?? I need to change opacity from 0 to 1 on before element, Can u edit this ?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. I don't think you can manipulate the style of a pseudo element through JS. You could however assign a class to the element which alters the opacity of the pseudo element.

Comment: Ah ok... I understand now, Thanks for answer!

Comment: Updated the answer to show you how to add/remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.menu-dropdown'), ':before')`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>