# How to select ::after element?

Tags: css, dom, xpath, css-selectors

I have a elements tree that looks similar to this one:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">...</div>
    ::after
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to select this '::after' element with xpath / css selectors?

Comment: You mean from browser JavaScript? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element

Comment: please explainn your question proper. other wise for css selector my answer is perfect as you mentioned the structure in html.

Comment: Sorry for being unprecise. Yes, of course I mean selecting this '::after' element from a browser / JS / etc. As I understand it is not possible. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.three::after{
  color:red;
  content:"text";
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

You can do it like this,

```
<style>
.three::after{
  //your styles
}
</style>
```

[image]