# How to obtain a pseudo-elements value?

Tags: javascript

In my example project I have two sections: *Table of Content* and *content*.

When editing the table of contents list, the pseudo element numbers (e.g. 1.1., 1.2 ...) get updated automatically. That's working fine.

---

What I get now in the browser is:

// table of content

1. Vegetables
   1.1. Carrot
   1.2. Cucumber
2. Fruits
   2.1. Apple
   2.2. Pineapple

// content

Vegetables
Carrot
Cucumber
Fruits
Apple
Pineapple

---

Now I like to use the pseudo element numbers in the content section as well. Which means after editing the table of contents the h1 elements shall be assigned to the correct pseudo element as well.

So that the content entries get the same pseudo element number like the table of content entries:

**How can I obtain the pseudo elements numbers in the content section as well?**

---

Unfortunately this article does not give the answer to my question:

[How to get pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element)

The described way of solving the problem in this article only returns the blank text:
counters(item, ". ")". "; (Instead of e.g. 1.1.)
**How can I obtain the pseudo element number values, e.g. 1.1. instead of counters(item, ". ")". ";?**

---

```js
function addTableOfContentEntriesToMainContent(){

  const tableOfContent = document.getElementById("tableOfContent");
  const content = document.getElementById("content");

  const liList = tableOfContent.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (let i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
    const h1 = document.createElement("h1");

    h1.textContent = liList[i].firstChild.textContent;

    content.appendChild(h1);
  }
  //this way does not return the pseudo Element number
  const element = liList[0];
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(element, '::before');
  const pseudoContent = style['content'];
  console.log(pseudoContent);
}

addTableOfContentEntriesToMainContent();
```

```css
ol { counter-reset: item; }
ol li { display: block; }
ol li::before {
  content: counters(item, ". ")". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol id="tableOfContent" >
  <li>Vegetables
    <ol>
      <li>Carrot</li>
      <li>Cucumber</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Fruits
    <ol>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Pineapple</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: CSS pseudo-elements are meant for styling purposes. Use some kind of hidden mark if you need the list index.

Comment: One can not access css `counter()`, `calc()`, `var()` values. One has to retrieve list-item values and compute the (nested) counter-number by an own approach that recursively walks the tree of a nested list-item nodes.

Comment: Off-topic, and maybe you like doing things this way, but IMO the only productive way to create a useful app is by writing logic (in plain JS, or using React/Vue/Angular/etc) that then outputs CSS to do what you need. You are doing the exact opposite: basing logic on CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a recursive function that will set the desired index to the list element. Something:

```js
const tableOfContent = document.getElementById("tableOfContent");
const content = document.getElementById("content");

eachLi(tableOfContent.querySelectorAll(':scope > li'));

function eachLi(lis, level = 0, parentIndex = "") {
  lis.forEach((el, index) => {
    appendH1(level, index, el.firstChild.textContent, parentIndex);
    const ol = el.querySelector(':scope > ol');
    if (ol) {
      level++;
      eachLi(ol.querySelectorAll(':scope > li'), level, `${parentIndex}${index + 1}.`);
    }
  });
}

function appendH1(level, index, text, parentIndex) {
  index++;
  let levelIndex = parentIndex ? `${parentIndex}${index}` : `${index}`;
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = `${levelIndex}. ${text}`;
  content.appendChild(h1);
}
```

```css
ol { counter-reset: item; }
ol li::before {
  content: counters(item, ". ")". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol id="tableOfContent">
  <li>Vegetables
    <ol>
      <li>Carrot</li>
      <li>Cucumber
      <ol>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
      </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Fruits
    <ol>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Pineapple</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<div id="content"></div>
```