# JQuery doesn't work with the after created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I want to create some css card with the data retrieved from json. It iterates fine, but I have a problem with the animation. When the user press a button, the card makes an animation and shows more info. The problem is that the animation works just with the first card. How can I solve it? Thank you.

[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/m3Vu7Lb4zYjhcmyv9zrp) you can find the full code.

This is the script linked to the info's button:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var $mainButton = $(".main-button"),
    $closeButton = $(".close-button"),
    $buttonWrapper = $(".button-wrapper"),
    $ripple = $(".ripple"),
    $layer = $(".layered-content");

$mainButton.on("click", function(){
    $ripple.addClass("rippling");
        $buttonWrapper.addClass("clicked").clearQueue().delay(1500).queue(function(){
        $layer.addClass("active");
    });
});

$closeButton.on("click", function(){
    $buttonWrapper.removeClass("clicked");
    $ripple.removeClass("rippling");
    $layer.removeClass("active");
});
})();
```

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript

Comment: id should be unique in same document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok your issue is you not detect good element. i have modify your `script.js`

```
 $(document).on("click",".main-button", function(){
            $(this).find(".ripple").addClass("rippling");
            $(this).closest("main").find(".button-wrapper").addClass("clicked").clearQueue().delay(1500).queue(function(){
            $(this).closest("main").find(".layered-content").addClass("active");
        });
    });
```

please try: http://plnkr.co/edit/qZmi3jJS4WVcN676OSP2

**UPDATE for close**

Try

```
$(document).on("click",".close-button", function(){
        $(this).closest("main").find(".button-wrapper").removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).closest("main").find(".ripple").removeClass("rippling");
        $(this).closest("main").find(".layered-content").removeClass("active");
    });
```

link : http://plnkr.co/edit/WKtJUqOwkEGnhb2Zc1HZ

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm sorry I have another problem.... the same problem but with the "close" button. I've tried this but it doesn't work: $(document).on('click', '.close-button', function () {
    $(this).find(".button-wrapper").removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).closest("main").find(".ripple").removeClass("rippling");
    $(this).closest("main").find(".layered-content").removeClass("active");
});