# Manipulate Pseudo Elements with Custom Fields

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

What I need to do is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin), but I need the user to be able to change the Pseudo Element using a custom field. Still learning JavaScript and this has been a struggle!

User needs ability to change ~ border-right: 500px solid #4679BD;

The custom field is ~ $angle = get_field('contact_angle_color');

Here is my code without my failed JavaScript attempts:

```css
.relative-wrap {
position: relative; 
min-height: 150px;
}

    .triangle-down-right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 54%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
    
    .triangle-down-right:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top:-500px;
    border-top: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid #4679BD;
    }
```

```html
<div class="triangle-down-right"></div>
```

Comment: You can't affect pseudo-elements with javascript...you need to swap out the class.

Comment: You can but it is messy. Why did you vote down my post?

Comment: I didn't downvote it. *Someone else* probably did because the question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand the part about *custom field*, but if you are planning on having unlimited control over pseudo-elements, well, good luck with that. Currently, **manipulating pseudo-elements with Javascript is possible through injecting inline css into DOM** as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript/12207551#answer-8051488), but it is not recommended unless, of course, you absolutely have to.

So, the other way to change pseudo-elements is to add/remove/modify class names on the element. Please see the example code below and the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9w4d6mts/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="direction" value="Change Direction">
<br>
<input type="button" id="color" value="Change Color">
<div id="demo" class="triangle-down-right alt"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.relative-wrap {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 150px;
}

.triangle-down-right,
.triangle-down-left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 54%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.triangle-down-right:after,
.triangle-down-left:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top:-500px;
    border-top: 500px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-down-right:after {
  border-right: 500px solid #4679BD;
}

.triangle-down-left:after {
  border-left: 500px solid #4679BD;
}

.triangle-down-right.alt:after,
.triangle-down-left.alt:after {
  border-color: transparent #D4679B transparent;
}
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('direction').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var d = document.getElementById('demo');
  d.className = (d.className.replace(' alt','') === "triangle-down-right") ? d.className.replace('right','left') : d.className.replace('left','right');
});

document.getElementById('color').addEventListener("click", function(){
    var d = document.getElementById('demo');
    console.log(d.className);
    d.className = (d.className.slice(-3) === "alt") ? d.className.replace(' alt','') : d.className + ' alt';
});
```

Basically, we are preparing the classes in CSS beforehand and switch them with Javascript based on user interaction. That's it.

Comment: I built a custom WordPress template and I need to give the user to have the ability to change the color of the angle (the custom post an area they can input a hex value). I could figure this out based on this but would you recommend only using Javascript to design this? Reason I am using CSS as much as possible is because their clients tend to use older web browsers.

Comment: I do not know what else you can use, apart from building a theme generator with PHP (and based on the project, this may mean some serious work). Another alternative may be predefining some styles for this angle, creating a separate stylesheet for each, and serving the relevant stylesheet based on the selected color by the user, but this also has 2 drawbacks: (1) An additional stylesheet means an additional server request, (2) There will be a limited number of colors.

Comment: Thank you very much for pulling me back because you are right. I will make it where it works on newer browsers with cleaner code and have default values set for older browsers.