# How to add css to pseudo elements using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-element

How can I change css of pseudo elements using javascript or jQuery.
Please don't give example of `:hover` I know how to access this attribute.

I want to know about `:before` and `:after` pesudo elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. but i already have css i don't want to append new one i like some inline css which we apply using `.css()` or any javascript method

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: if you want to apply css using JS you can have a class with the desired style and just add and remove on requirement

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902600/manipulate-css-before-selector-with-jquery/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: @guradio we can apply using tag also. 
@gurvinder372 i have tried `jQuery('body:before').css({'display':'none !important'});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is a Static style you can define a class with the :before ore :after and add the Class using JQuery.`.simpelClass:after { fooo: bar}`

```
$(element).addClass('simpleClass');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. it's working.
i have found another one `document.styleSheets[0].addRule("body:before","display:none !important")`

Answer (score -1):

You can style your element and its pseudo elements adding and removing a class:

**script.js**

```
document.getElementById("element_id").addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
    document.getElementById("element_id").classList.add("link_active")
}, false)
document.getElementById("element_id").addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
    document.getElementById("element_id").classList.remove("link_active")

}, false)
```

**style.css**

```
#element_id::after, #element_id::before{
    content: "|";
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#element_id::after{
    transform: translateX(10px);
    animation: after_active 0.5s ease-out  forwards;
}
@keyframes after_active{
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
#element_id::before{
    transform: translateX(-10px);
    animation: before_active 0.5s ease-out  forwards;
}
@keyframes before_active{
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
```

The script will translate the pseudo elements while the opacity is changed