# Changing body background image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background image using javascript.  I've set the background up like this;

```css
body {
    background: black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
  
body:before {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: url('http://www.dafont.com/forum/attach/orig/1/6/166803.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1; /* Keep the background behind the content */
    height: 100%; width: 100%; /* Using Glen Maddern's trick /via @mente */
    transform: scale(1);
    filter: blur(13px);
}
```

I'm using the above CSS to create a background image with a blur that does not affect elements placed above it.  This works.  My issue is I would like to change the background image at random intervals.  I am unable to do so.  I have used;

```html
document.body.style.backgroundImage
$('body').css( 'background-image', artUrl );
document.getElementById('body')
```

All have failed, I think the issue maybe due to the fact the image is set in body:before.  Is there anyway to change the background image using javascript and still be able to have a blur without effecting elements above it?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You JS is meaningless. Is that all the code you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)

Comment: How is it meaning less, those are the 3 most common ways of changing the background, and all have failed, what more do you need?

Comment: meaningless in the context you posted it in. I thought your code is literally that.

Comment: *`Using Glen Maddern's trick /via @mente`* sorry for the bummer but that's no-one's trick. Nothing tricky there, it's just the way it is handling absolute elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image)

Comment: I am able to access the pseudo-element in the following manner;

`document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[1].style.background = 'url("' + artUrl + '") 0% 0% / cover';`


Its ugly but it works, I think it will change when I make CSS changes to the document, but at least now I know what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it has something to do with the pseudo element. Unfortunately there isn't a way to manipulate this with JavaScript. You could, however, use JavaScript to create a style tag that would have a higher specificity.

```
var css = 'body:before { background: url(\'dblogo_150.png\') }';
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create new classes with attached pseudo elements to do this, and use Javascript to switch between them. For example your CSS might look like:

```
.background--first:before {
  background: url(first.jpg);
}

.background--second:before {
  background: url(second.jpg);
}

.background--third:before {
  background: url(third.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Of course it is, since after all he is targeting the pseudo element, not the actual body element. And you cannot apply classes to pseudo elements.

Comment: The urls are unknown before the document is loaded.  They are completely random, so this will not work, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **separate element** that you'll **blur**;
don't use `body` neither `body:before` or `:after`, why complicate, right?!

Use several **child elements**, hide all but first, set a `transition` and a `.show` in CSS,  handle (actually **toggle**) that class using **JS** (**jQuery** in our case)

```js
/**
 *   BACKGROUND FADER
 */
(function(){ 
  
  var $slides = $("#background").children(),
      tot = $slides.length, // how many slides
      c = 0,                // simple counter
      itv;
  
  function anim() {
    c = ++c % tot; // c = random? Do what you like
    $slides.removeClass("show").eq( c ).addClass("show");
  }
  
  itv = setInterval(anim, 3000); // Start loop!
  
}());
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}


body{
  color:#fff;
  background: black;
}

#background{
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  z-index: -999;
  filter: blur(10px);
  overflow:hidden;
}

#background > div{
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  background: none 50% / cover;
  transition: 1s; -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

#background > div + div{  /* all but first one */
  opacity: 0;
}
#background > div.show{   /* class handled by jQuery */
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="background">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/0bf/fff?text=0);"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/f0b/fff?text=1);"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600/0fb/fff?text=2);"></div>
</div>

<!-- put other page content here. -->

<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited : There is no way to select the pseudo element, but you can add style to the page like this:

try change this:

```
$('body').css( 'background-image', artUrl );
```

To

```
$('body').append('<style>body:before{background: url(' + src + ')}</style>');
```

The style appends to the page will override the one in css file.

```js
var src = 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.3-hp2x.gif';

$('body').append('<style>body:before{background: url(' + src + ')}</style>');
```

```css
body {
    background: black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
  
body:before {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: url('https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%; width: 100%; 
    transform: scale(1);
    filter: blur(13px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: The background-image is on the pseudo-element, so changing it on the body won't have any effect

Comment: also isn't  just `overflow: hidden;` *simpler?*

Comment: also this does not answers the bg image change at random and I see no point in putting an enormous useless google doodle gif as demo ()

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It totally would answer the question, why the change is not working, if there wasn't the real problem that you cannot easily manipulate pseudo elements. The overflow is just c&p from the question.

Comment: @Christoph that's why I tought initially that djfdev suggested about using 3 distinct elements :D than after your comment realized noones actually passing the *useful answer* line here.

Comment: So this answer has promise, he was correct the jQuery method was improperly constructed, however this simply places the new image under the old one.  The old one has transparencies so I can see the new image beneath it.  My goal is to completely replace the previous image.  I will keep tinkering with this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I edited the answer, the above code should work as the append style will replace the on defined in the css file