# Is there a way to style p5js sliders using pure JavaScript and without HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, slider, p5.js

I have a few sliders in javascript (specifically using p5.js library) for which some styling needs to be added (add labels and do some colouring). Is it possible to do so in javascript, without using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p5 sliders are [p5 Elements](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element), and can be styled with functions like Element.style and Element.class. In this case, you can directly style the slider with something like `slider.style('background', 'red');`

If you want to style a *pseudo-element* (like the actual tab on the slider), it seems a bit more tricky, especially without CSS. You can read more about the various approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript). If you want a solution that runs in only JavaScript, you could add a class then dynamically insert a stylesheet into DOM, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8051488/6184972).

#### Edit: Adding Labels

It doesn't seem that p5.dom has a function for creating `label` elements, but you can create `div` elements using `createDiv`, and then combine elements together. So if you want a label on the left side, you can do something like:

```
label = createDiv('Red');
label.position(30, 30);  
slider = createSlider(0, 255, 100);
slider.parent(label);
```

If you want the label on the right side, it's a little more tricky:

```
group = createDiv('');
group.position(30, 30);  
slider = createSlider(0, 255, 100);
slider.parent(group);
label = createSpan('Red');
label.parent(group);
```

References:

- https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element
- [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)

Comment: I just want to add some text next to it as a label! how would I achieve that? more importantly what would be the argument for that?

Comment: Hi Abby, I've updated my answer, it's a little complicated to write in just a comment