# How to "null" content value of pseudo :before element by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have series of buttons with different classes consisting ":before" pseudo elements with different predefined "content" values.
Is there is a way to "null" content value  of all buttons using javascript (not jquery)?.

```
.button 1:before{content:"xxx";} .button 2:before{content:"yyy";} .button 3:before{content:"zzz";}...etc.
```

to

```
.button 1:before{content:" ";} .button 2:before{content:" ";} .button 3:before{content:" ";}...etc.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's one-liner trick:

[insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) - Supported by all modern browsers: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQPopa)

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.button:after, .button:before {content: " ";}',0);
```

addRule - Supported by all modern browsers except FF

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.button:after, .button:before','content: " ";');
```

Comment: TypeError: "document.styleSheets[0].addRule is not a function"

Comment: @Serg -  you are right ... I updated my answer: it is preferable to use insertRule because it works in all browsers

Comment: "insertRule" doesn't shows an error but does nothing, doesn't overwrite predefined content's value.

Comment: @Serg - This is strange. Which browser are you using? I created an example on codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQPopa . Does it work for you?

Comment: "insertRule" with 'content: " "!important;  works perfectly. Thank you Denis.

Comment: @Serg - You welcome. But remember: !important - it's an pure evil :) Thus its desirable to override the styles by weights of selectors - https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity

Answer (score 1):

To clear css content property you need to add specific class to elements which will clear that property.

Css:

```
.clear-content {
   content: none; //you can add !important to make sure you will override other styles
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector(".button_1").classList.add('clear-content');
```

You can also go through all items for example buttons:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.add('clear-content');
});
```

Comment: I missed ":before" in my sample, so it should look like: .button 1:before{content:"xxx";} to .button 1:before{content:" ";}, that's probably why your codes won't work. Sorry for the mess.