# Javascript - on-click function giving unexpected result

Tags: javascript

In my project, I have a div, which is set to `display: none;` by default. When a user clicks an image, I use the onclick function to attempt to display the image. However this method does not work for some reason.

Here is my HTML:

```
<img onclick="hamburgerFunc()" class="hamburger-btn" width="38px" src="{% static 'hamburgericon.png' %}" alt="Image of hamburger icon"> 

<div class="box arrow-top"></div>
<script src="{% static 'home.js' %}"></script>
```

JS:

```
function hamburgerFunc(objs) {
    objs = document.getElementsByClassName("box arrow-top")
    objs.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
.box.arrow-top:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    border-top: none;
    display: none;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  }
```

The **box arrow-top** is the div I want to display once the image is pressed. Does anybody know why this code is not working? Thank you.

Comment: since you're using a pseudo selector, I'll suggest to follow the recommendation on the response on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207551/291833

Answer (score 3):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns not a single element but an a live HTMLCollection. And you either need to iterate over all of them and set the `style` for each of them individually. Or if you only expect on the element you would directly access it `objs[0].style.display = …`

```
const objs = document.getElementsByClassName("box arrow-top")
objs[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
```

or

```
const objs = document.getElementsByClassName("box arrow-top")
for (const obj of objs) {
  obj.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
const obj = document.querySelector(".box.arrow-top")
obj.style.display = 'inline-block';
```

or if you really have multiple elements:

```
const objs = document.querySelectorAll(".box.arrow-top")
for (const obj of objs) {
  obj.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

**UPDATE**

[`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) creates a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), those elements are not part of the DOM and cannot be selected.

What you want to do is to remove the `display: none;` from your css rule. And e.g. change the rule to `.box.arrow-top.visible:after`

```
.box.arrow-top.visible:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  }
```

And then do:

```
obj.style.classList.add("visible");
```

Comment: take a look at the documentation of  `Document.getElementsByClassName` you've linked it. It does  support more than one class as the selector, each of which should be separated by a whitespace

Comment: @t.niese Hello. Please check my original post, as I want to add that class to the query selector. I have tried 1 method, however It does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) creates a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), those elements are not part of the DOM and cannot be selected. So you don't want to display the box but that element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hamburgerFunc() {
    document.querySelector(".box.arrow-top").style.display = 'inline-block'
}
```

```css
.box.arrow-top{
    display:none;
    background:orange;
    padding:1em;
    position:relative;
    width: 38px;
}

.box.arrow-top:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  }
```

```html
<img onclick="hamburgerFunc()" class="hamburger-btn" width="38px" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="Image of hamburger icon"> 

<div class="box arrow-top"></div>
```

Comment: Hello. Please check my original post, as I want to add that class to the be displayed as-well. I have tried 1 method, following your patter, however It does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @eweee see my edit, is that what you're looking for?