# how to change css background color using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am having difficulty to change background color using JavaSript. I only want to change color of background property that is inside .diagnosis-kit-inner .nav-tabs .nav-item.active:after. Can anyone help me please.Can anyone help me please? Thanks

```js
function changeColor() {
  var changeColor = document.getElementsByClassName(".diagnosis-kit-inner .nav-tabs .nav-item.active:after");

  changeColor.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

```css
.diagnosis-kit-inner .nav-tabs .nav-item.active:after {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagnosis-kit-inner ">
  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</a>
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `onclick="changColor()"`

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I have fixed this error. Can u please help me out to sort out this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the style of a psudo-selector, but you can use a [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) for the background color and assign a default at the document `:root`.

You can then overwrite this using JavaScript by calling `setProperty` on the `style` of the `documentElement`.

This was adapted from this answer: [*Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)

```js
function changeActiveColor() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--nav-item-active-bg', 'blue');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --nav-item-active-bg: white;
}

.diagnosis-kit-inner .nav-tabs .nav-item.active:after {
  color: #CCC;
  content: 'Active';
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: var(--nav-item-active-bg); /* Dynamic var prop */
}
```

```html
<div class="diagnosis-kit-inner">
  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item active"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="changeActiveColor()">Change Color</a>
```