# How to set a pseudo element directly to html with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to solve a challenge and it requires me to write all the html, css and JS all in one JS file. I'm having trouble figuring out how can I set a pseudo element to a 'div' using JS.

The code for setting my div is:

```
let myDiv = document.createElement('div')
myDiv.className = 'cart-container'
myDiv.style.cssText = "height: 440px; width: 400px; margin: auto; overflow-y:auto;"
```

in CSS the pseudo elements would look like this:

```
.cart-container::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 10px;
}

.cart-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #30808d;
  height: 100px;
}
```

how could I inset that CSS code to my 'div' using JS instead of using CSS?

Comment: Just a side note: are you sure `myDiv.className = 'cart-container'` is correct? Shouldn't it be `myDiv.classList.add('cart-container')` or `myDiv.setAttribute('class', 'cart-container')`?

Comment: @secan - that approach is a bit older and `classList` is probably preferred today, but [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) does work for this purpose.

Comment: @AlexanderNied, thanks; I did not know that :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)

Comment: For what concerns your actual question, I think you will have to use one of the approaches suggested in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/311052/14201528 (the question is about pseudo-classes but you can apply the same logic for pseudo-elements too)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()` method to insert styles for pseudo elements. I've added a small example below on how to make use of it:

```js
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 100px; background-color: green; }");
```

```css
#test {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: would this assume I don't have a css file? for this purpose I cant use one everything created needs to be in JS

Comment: @rams141 yes the css here has no role at all. It's just there to have a large enough div to display the scrollbar. Even if you create everything from JS, the document will still have a stylesheet in which you can insert rule just the way you add styles in css.