# How to specify scrollbar properties using javascript objects rather than css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

In css:

```css
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--back-color);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    width: 5px;
  }
```

How would I specify those properties using a javascript object which would be passed into the style property of a `div` tag?

Comment: There's not a direct way to set those, here are a couple work-arounds: uses a parent-class to add/remove styles that are previously set in css: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207551/4375502 and one that is a function to use javascript to dynamically write css to a style tag on the page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8051488/4375502