# Having an issue from material UI visibility password in the microsoft edge browser checked the different ways

Tags: html, css, reactjs, redux, microsoft-edge

Having an issue from material UI visibility password in the microsoft edge browser checked the different ways.

[image: Click to see the image in microsoft edge]

And Followed This

https://codesandbox.io/s/inputadornments-material-demo-forked-4euh8?file=/demo.js:549-559

ALso the material ui docs of input adornment
https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#InputAdornments.js

Basically we need to have only one visibility as the default material UI had provided but in microsoft edge browser we are receiving the 2 visibility eye-Icons tried to approach the different method.

I had attached the code reference

```
  <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: "25ch" }} variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-password">
        Password
      </InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput
        id="outlined-adornment-password"
        type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
        value={values.password}
        onChange={handleChange("password")}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
              onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
              edge="end"
            >
              {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        label="Passwords"
      />
    </FormControl>
```

Comment: Do those other two "password" fields suffer the same issue? It's also a completely different icon. Are you sure it isn't the "native" browser adding it? What version of Edge are you currently testing with?

Comment: Which version of Edge? Newer Edge are Chromium

Comment: @DrewReese I am using edge Version 93.0.961.52 (Official build) (64-bit) which is upto date u can also test from ur side in edge browser it's coming same

Answer (score 2):

If we try to see the file structure of the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputadornments-material-demo-forked-4euh8?file=/demo.js), you will find the **index.html** file under the **Public** folder.

[image]

Open the **index.html** file and add the code below in the **style** tag.

```
<style>
      input::-ms-reveal,
      input::-ms-clear {
        display: none;
      }
</style>
```

Save the file and run the example in the MS Edge browser.

**Output in the MS Edge (Version 93.0.961.52) browser.**

[image]

You could notice that it is not showing the 2 eye icons as you have stated in the question.

You could do the same in your actual code to avoid the said issue with the MS Edge browser.

You could also place the above CSS code in the CSS files for this example. As per your requirement, you could modify it.

Comment: can u add inline style for this code :https://codesandbox.io/s/inputadornments-material-demo-forked-cbszk

Comment: In my suggestion, we are using the pseudo-element. Based on my search result, it looks like we can't apply styles to pseudo-elements in JavaScript. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8046436/10309381). In that case, you could keep that CSS code in the **Style** tag.