# How to get the style of an element with psuedo-class (:focus for example)

Tags: javascript, html, css, getcomputedstyle

I would like to get certain css property (for example the `border-color`) of any elements, but when its on a 'non-base' states, such as focus and hover. For example:

```html
<style>
    .input {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .input:focus {
        outline: none;
        border-color: green;
    }
</style>

<input type="text" class="input">

<script>
    let input = document.querySelector('.input');
    const inputBorderColor = window.getComputedStyle(input).getPropertyValue('border-color');
    console.log(inputBorderColor); // rgb(255, 0, 0)
</script>
```

Using `getComputedStyle`, I can grab the border color of the input for the 'base' state, but how do I get the border color for when the input is on focus (in this case `border-color: green`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(input).color)
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/disaladamsas/pen/KKvNZYz?editors=1111

Comment: With this solution, the value only becomes available when the user focuses on the input. Is there a way to get the value on page load (without having the need for user to interact with the input element)?

Comment: i think you should use css variables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript

Comment: Under a more common
 case, yes I would use css variables. But what I'm trying to achieve here is to generate a js object containing css properties related to the input.

Answer (score 0):

the styles you write for hover and focus and other pseudo-classes are only applied to element when the element has the pseudo-class, a quick solution is to make the `eventListener` for the focus event like the previous answer and then triggering that event by JS on the load time

something like :

```
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
let color = '';
input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    color = window.getComputedStyle(input).color;
});
input.dispatchEvent( new Event('focus') )
```