# How to move custom text cursor when typing in input box?

Tags: html, jquery, css, react-native, css-selectors

How to move custom text cursor when typing in input box?

```css
.cursor {
  position: relative;
}

.cursor i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10%;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
  <input type="text" />
  <i></i>
</div>
```

Although this successfully creates a blinking, rectangular, and blue text cursor, it remains in the same position once I type text into the input box. How can I modify the above code so that the cursor moves, similar to Mac/Linux terminals?

Comment: What is the name of the class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430615/halting-css-animation-with-after-selector-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get value of your input and put it inside a hidden div to get the [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth).

Make sure that you set the same **font family** and the same **font size** for your input and the div "mask" to make it work correctly.

I added +3 px to make a correction.

---

I used css [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) for the left move.

```js
let elemDiv = document.getElementById("mask"),
  elemInput = document.getElementById("typing");

elemInput.oninput = function() {
  elemDiv.innerText = elemInput.value;
  
  // css version
  $(".cursor i").css({"left":(elemDiv.clientWidth + 3) + "px"});
  
  // debug infos 
  console.clear();
  console.log((elemDiv.clientWidth + 3) + "px");
}
```

```css
.cursor {
  position: relative;
}
.cursor i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10%;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

#typing {
  width:100%;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
}

#mask {
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  overflow:auto;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
<input type="text" id="typing" />
<i></i>
</div>
<div id='mask'></div>
```

But you can also do it with [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```js
let elemDiv = document.getElementById("mask"),
  elemInput = document.getElementById("typing");

elemInput.oninput = function() {
  elemDiv.innerText = elemInput.value;
  
  // animated version
  $(".cursor i").animate({"left":(elemDiv.clientWidth + 3) + "px"}, 50);
  
  // debug infos 
  console.clear();
  console.log((elemDiv.clientWidth + 3) + "px");
}
```

```css
.cursor {
  position: relative;
}
.cursor i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10%;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

#typing {
  width:100%;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
}

#mask {
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  overflow:auto;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
<input type="text" id="typing" />
<i></i>
</div>
<div id='mask'></div>
```