# Changing hamburger menu color with eventlistener and scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, event-listener

Im trying to change the color of my burger bar lines. I used an eventlistener and I try to target the spans that make up the burgermenu lines, by giving the span a class "span". as u can see here

```
 var distFromTop = document.querySelector(".om-mux").offsetTop;
 var distFromTop2 = document.querySelector(".galleri").offsetTop;
 var distFromTop3 = document.querySelector(".event-sektion").offsetTop;

 window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
     var scroll = this.scrollY;
     if (scroll > distFromTop && scroll < distFromTop2) {
         document.querySelector(".span").style.backgroundColor = "black";
     } else if (scroll > distFromTop2 && scroll < distFromTop3) {
        document.querySelector(".span:before").style.backgroundColor = "white";
     } else if (scroll > distFromTop3){
        document.querySelector(".span").style.backgroundColor = "black";

     } else {
        document.querySelector(".span").style.backgroundColor = "white";

     }
 })`
```

The code runs well, but problem is that this only affects the middle span, because of the fact that the upper and bottom line are styled as such:

```
`  .menu-btn > span,
  .menu-btn > span::before,
  .menu-btn > span::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition-duration: .25s;
  }`
```

How do I target span:before & span:after? can I do something like this?        `document.querySelector(".span:before").style.backgroundColor = "white";`

Comment: Instead of changing background color in js, add your element a new className. In css, mention that `.new-class`  should have `background: newColor;` and alos say this for it's `::after` and `::before`. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English is not my first Language so please bear with me. Try adding new class to span when you scroll and give that class background-color property in your CSS file. Example

Instead of this

```
document.querySelector(".span").style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

Try

```
document.querySelector(".span").classList.add('black');
```

and add this class css property in your css file.

```
  .menu-btn > span.span.black::before{
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

reference: [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)

The closest to changing the style of a pseudo-element in JavaScript is adding and removing classes, then using the pseudo-element with those classes. An example to hide the scrollbar:

CSS

```
.hidden-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("editor").classList.add('hidden-scrollbar');
```

To later remove the same class, you could use:

```
document.getElementById("editor").classList.remove('hidden-scrollbar');
```