# How can I load a page using jquery then use the CSS AND HTML?

Tags: jquery

I have an html file that looks basically like...

```
<style>
    some css
</style>

<h1>...</h1>
<p>...</p>
<form>
    ...
</form>

<script>
    some javascript
</script>
```

I can successfully load this into a div using...

```
$('#signup').load('path/to/html');
```

The content is loaded, the javascript executes, but the css doesn't load in the HEAD section and is therefore invalid markup.

I know I can load a *separate* css file using something like...

```
$("head").append("<link />");
var CSS = $("head").children(":last");
CSS.attr({
    "rel": "stylesheet",
    "type": "text/css",
    "href": "url/to.css"
});
```

...shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1948571/1024808 .  But I can't figure out how to load the css AND the HTML using only one page call.  I had an idea of using the .load() methods option to *"specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted"*.  http://api.jquery.com/load/ .  But that then discards the rest of the document and would require a second page load, AFAIK.

Thanks

Comment: Dynamically loaded html should have relevant css applied automatically.  I think your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Could potentially be a selectivity problem as well.

Comment: @AdamRackis is right. Your CSS isn't correct, your HTML is malformed, or some other issue.

Comment: From everything I read it does but is "non compliant".  Last thing I need is a browser breaking it later.  According to the spec <style> MUST be in the <head> section to be valid.  Question edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

use **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**  :Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now *and in the future.*

Comment: >"Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks."

Comment: Can you tell me the names of these methods ?

Comment: According to your link `.on()` .