# "unrecognized expression" in jQuery selector when using "::"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For some reason I can't get this function to work..I've included the code and error from Chrome.

Is it the `::` that's causing a problem? It's driving me nuts. Variable 101 here hehe.

**EDIT:** I'm trying to call a pseudo-element, which cannot be styled via .css().

```
var grabColor = $('.sb-custom-color').val();
var placeholder = 'form .entry-form-wrap input::-webkit-input-placeholder';

$(placeholder).css("color", grabColor);
```

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: form .entry-form-wrap input::-webkit-input-placeholder`

Comment: change the :: and find out. Problem solving 101. :)

Comment: `$.css` changes the `style` property.  you can't change the `style` of a pseudo-element.  you'll have to modify an [actual DOM stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleSheet) programmatically.

Comment: Which element are you trying to select using `placeholder`?

Comment: @Eevee Thanks man. I was going to do that initially...but was trying to avoid static css in my source.

Comment: @MikeBarwick didn't mean to be rude. You said "Is it the :: that's causing a problem?". What exactely are you trying to get with input::-webkit-input-placeholder? BTW the downvote wasn't mine!

Comment: @SandyLee an input field...

Comment: Can you simply give a class to that input field and write ... input.className ... or even an attribute <input rel="-webkit-input-placeholder"> and select it by doing input[rel="-webkit-input-placeholder"]?

Comment: you don't need static CSS in your source for this; there are DOM methods for creating and manipulating stylesheets entirely from JS.  (or you could just populate one with `$.text`, i suppose.)

Comment: @vyx.ca No worries at all. I'm trying to dynamically change the color of the placeholder text on some form inputs. Ah - I could care less about the downvote. I'm not here to earn points and flex my muscles. Just here to learn. :)

Comment: Why don't you assign it a `class` or an `id`?

Comment: User dynamically changes the color for a customizable form in our application. Can't be a class and @vyx.ca that won't work customizing placeholder text. It needs to be called directly. As per my code. That's also why many DOM methods probably don't work well either. Guess I'm stuck using style tag within source...agh.

Comment: Could you proved us with a fiddle. I'm sure there's a way! There's always a way!! :)

Comment: I think this has several decent options I"m going to explore! Thanks ya'll for your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351633/how-do-i-load-css-rules-dynamically-in-webkit-safari-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select pseudo elements with jQuery or in JavaScript for that matter. Instead create a style tag or modify a style element.